# IntelliJ 10/11 AutoComplete broken with SWC dependencies from SWF Project

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, intellij-idea

I am working on setting up a project for some developers and helping them componentize some of their code into a swc. I have created an Ant build process for them, but when setting up dependencies in IntelliJ's Flex Facets we are seeing that code that is referenced from the Libraries is not autocompleting nor is it letting us step into classes accross libraries. I am sure this works as I have done it with a Maven setup before. I just wonder if there is some setting I am missing when doing ti manually as these guys are not willing to go the route of Maven yet.

Here is a quick screenshot of our test SWF that depends on two SWC libraries:

[image: Here is a quick screenshot of our test SWF that depends on two SWC libraries]

Notice that in this sample class the code that lives in the client-core project does not show up as code completed (it's red) but it compiles fine with Ant.

[image]

Any ideas as to what we are doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answered in InteliJ IDEA forum: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5447354#5447354

Comment: Yeah it looks like importing via Maven doesn't work with multiple module outputs. Have reconfigured the project with Flex Facets and it works fine now when not using Java Modules at the top level. Looking forward to the new way of configuring Flex projects in Intellij 12 (or 11.1,11.2,11.3)